# Javascript if else statement with OR and IS NOT

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, global-variables

**HTML**

```
<div class="big"></div>
<div class="small"></div>

<!--
swapping out var that is set in body
-->
<script>
    // var;
    // var color;
    // var color =;
    // var color = '';
    // var color = 'cat';
    // var color = 'big';
     var color = 'small';
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
.big {height:100px;width:100px;background:#eaeaea;}
.small {height:50px;width:50px;background:#eaeaea;}
```

**JS & jQuery**

what I am trying to say is

1. do somethign if var is not set
2. do the same thing if var is set but not set to big or small (the var strings I want to account for)
3. if it is set to big do something different
4. if it is set to small do something different

What ends up happening is that first condition always runs because when big *is* set small *is not* set, and when small *is* set big *is not* set

```
if ( typeof color === 'undefined' || color != 'big' || color != 'small' ) {
    $('.big,.small').css('background-color', '#333');       
} else if ( color === 'big' ) {
    $('.big').css('background-color', '#fad400');
} else if ( color === 'small' ) {
    $('.small').css('background-color', '#fad400');
}

$('body').append('<div>' + color + '</div>')
```

How do I write this if statement to account for all scenarios of what my var color could be while still targeting two specific options?

here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/designaroni/4zba5yo9/

Comment: Why do you have triple equal signs? '==='

Comment: That's recommended practice, @derstrom8. It checks not just value but data type as well.

Comment: Brilliant. I learn something new every day! =)

Comment: Stop those typeof your_var === 'undefined' checks. Do not use undefined at all, it is confusing. Go with your_var == null which checks for null OR undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You need to code it like this:

```
if ( typeof color === 'undefined' || (color != 'big' && color != 'small') ) {
    $('.big,.small').css('background-color', '#333');       
} else if ( color === 'big' ) {
    $('.big').css('background-color', '#fad400');
} else if ( color === 'small' ) {
    $('.small').css('background-color', '#fad400');
}
```

This way, you are saying: if it's undefined OR (not big AND not small)

EDIT: Per tadman's suggestion below, this is simpler:

```
if ( color === 'big' ) {
    $('.big').css('background-color', '#fad400');
} else if ( color === 'small' ) {
    $('.small').css('background-color', '#fad400');
} else {
    $('.big,.small').css('background-color', '#333');       
}
```

Comment: It might be worth promoting the `big` and `small` tests to the front of the line so the last test already has those excluded.